# struggling to save a lists of lists

Tags: python

I have recently encountered the problem of trying to make a list of lists. when ever the program has been run, it prints the generations of greenfly, depending on how many generations the user wants to see.

```
generation 1  [10, 10, 10] Total 30
generation 2 [20, 10, 10] Total 40
generation 3 [20, 20, 10] Total 50
generation 4 [40, 20, 20] Total 80
generation 5 [40, 40, 20] Total 100
generation 6 [80, 40, 40] Total 160
```

And if i wanted to display these results (e.g. to a csv) i would need all of the information from these results to do so. However when ever i print the variable that holds this information (in this case 'greenfly') it only prints the final generation that the program ran.

```
print(greenfly)
```

(what it looks like)

```
[80,40,40]
```

How would you run the program so it printed all of the other information that has been displayed:

```
generation 1  [10, 10, 10] Total 30
generation 2 [20, 10, 10] Total 40
generation 3 [20, 20, 10] Total 50
generation 4 [40, 20, 20] Total 80
generation 5 [40, 40, 20] Total 100
generation 6 [80, 40, 40] Total 160
```

please could you help?........ (The full code is displayed below)

```
 greenfly = [popJuveniles,popAdults,popAdults]
    Total1 = greenfly[0]+greenfly[1]+greenfly[2]
    print("generation 1 ",greenfly,"Total",Total1)
    '''popall=[greenfly,Total1]
    print (popall)'''

    generation = 1
    while generations!= 1:

        generation = generation + 1
        generations = generations - 1
        juviniles=greenfly[1]*2
        Adult=greenfly[0]
        Seniles=greenfly[1]
        greenfly=[juviniles,Adult,Seniles]

        Total = greenfly[0]+greenfly[1]+greenfly[2]


        print("generation",generation,greenfly,"Total",Total)



if Menuchoice =='4':
    print("You have chosen option 4 ")

    print(greenfly)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
greenfly=[juviniles,Adult,Seniles]
```

This line is being called on every iteration of the loop so any data contained inside `greenfly` is being overwritten each time the loop runs, resulting in the behavior you are seeing.

A way to combat this would be to use `greenfly.append([juviniles,Adult,Seniles])`

This should return `[[10, 10, 10], [20, 10, 10], [20, 20, 10], ....]` and so on.

Remember to set `greenfly = []` before the loop.